# Java compiler rejects variable declaration with parameterized inner class

Tags: java, generics, groovy, inner-classes

I have some Groovy code which works fine in the Groovy bytecode compiler, but the Java stub generated by it causes an error in the Java compiler. I think this is probably yet another bug in the Groovy stub generator, but I really can't figure out why the Java compiler doesn't like the generated code.

Here's a truncated version of the generated Java class (please excuse the ugly formatting):

```
@groovy.util.logging.Log4j() public abstract class AbstractProcessingQueue
<T>  extends nz.ac.auckland.digitizer.AbstractAgent  implements
    groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
        protected int retryFrequency;
        protected java.util.Queue<nz.ac.auckland.digitizer.AbstractProcessingQueue.ProcessingQueueMember<T>> items;
        public AbstractProcessingQueue
        (int processFrequency, int timeout, int retryFrequency) {
             super ((int)0, (int)0);
    }

    private enum ProcessState
      implements
    groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
        NEW, FAILED, FINISHED;
    }

    private class ProcessingQueueMember<E>  extends java.lang.Object  implements
    groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
        public ProcessingQueueMember
        (E object) {}
    }
}
```

The offending line in the generated code is this:

```
protected java.util.Queue<nz.ac.auckland.digitizer.AbstractProcessingQueue.ProcessingQueueMember<T>> items;
```

which produces the following compile error:

```
[ERROR] C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\digitizer\target\generated-sources\groovy-stubs\main\nz\ac\auckland\digitizer\AbstractProcessingQueue.java:[14,96] error: improperly formed type, type arguments given on a raw type
```

The column index of 96 in the compile error points to the `<T>` parameterization of the `ProcessingQueueMember` type. But `ProcessingQueueMember` is not a raw type as the compiler claims, it is a generic type:

```
private class ProcessingQueueMember
<E>  extends java.lang.Object  implements
groovy.lang.GroovyObject { ...
```

I am very confused as to why the compiler thinks that the type `Queue<ProcessingQueueMember<T>>` is invalid. The Groovy source compiles fine, and the generated Java code looks perfectly correct to me too. What am I missing here? Is it something to do with the fact that the type in question is a nested class?

(in case anyone is interested, I have filed [this bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5675) relating to the issue in this question)

Edit: Turns out this was indeed a stub compiler bug- this issue is now fixed in 1.8.9, 2.0.4 and 2.1, so if you're still having this issue just upgrade to one of those versions. :)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this compiler error - which compiler are you using?

Comment: Oracle jdk1.7.0_05. Which reminds me, I need to update it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `ProcessingQueueMember` class is a non-static inner class of `AbstractProcessingQueue`, its body can refer to the `T` type parameter of `AbstractProcessingQueue`. Thus, a non-raw reference to the `ProcessingQueueMember` must supply both the type arguments. For example,

```
protected java.util.Queue<AbstractProcessingQueue<T>.ProcessingQueueMember<T>> items;
```

will compile. This code is probably excessively generic. I believe you actually want one of these two alternatives:

1. Make `ProcessingQueueMember<E>` static (i.e. a nested class as opposed to an inner class)
2. Remove the type parameter from `ProcessingQueueMember`

I do not know anything about the groovy stub generator, but maybe there is some way to annotate your groovy code to express this?

Comment: But `items` is an instance member, so that syntax seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks- declaring the member class and the associated state enum as static within the enclosing class solved my problem. I have very little experience with nested classes, so had not previously appreciated the distinction between static and non-static nested classes.

Comment: @PaulBellora you're right, it would have been possible to just have `java.util.Queue<ProcessingQueueMember<T>>` since the declaration but I wanted to show what that is implicitly expanded to.

Comment: Ah, in that case this *is* a bug in the Groovy stub compiler. In my Groovy code the declaration was simply `Queue<ProcessingQueueMember<T>>`, but the generated expansion was incorrect. I'm tempted to file a bug report, but the last stub compiler bug I reported was marked as a blocker and has since been left unassigned for months...

Comment: @Johansensen You should try not making `ProcessingQueueMember` generic, assuming that the type in the queue member must match the type of the `AbstractProcessingQueue`.

Comment: Since I have to retrieve the generic object from the member object, making the member class generic is the only way of knowing at compile-time that the object I'm retrieving is of the same type that I passed in, without actually knowing what that type is. It's all a bit academic seeing as Groovy is dynamic and can do whatever it wants, but I try to use type-safety constructs so as to catch coding errors at compile time rather than runtime. And generics are a compile-time construct so not going to impact performance anyhow. :)

Comment: Err, that is to say, I have to retrieve the object of the generic type, not the generic object itself. *confusion*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the generic type parameter of the class that contains the variable declaration (`protected java.util.Queue<nz.ac.auckland.digitizer.AbstractProcessingQueue.ProcessingQueueMember<T>> items;`) is missing?

Comment: Nope- I have added more code to the question so that you can see that this parameter is there.